# How to return the name of the column clicked by the user in plotly

Tags: python, pyqt5, plotly

I have an application on PyQt5 (a code snippet is attached), in which I put a diagram on plotly. This diagram is formed from a dataframe (link: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Oyk3tHlAjwWPYA). I need to make the program return to the click_event function the name of the column that the user clicked on.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

import pandas as pd

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px


app = QApplication([])
tab = QTabWidget()
tab.setGeometry(
    0, 0,
    QApplication.desktop().width(), QApplication.desktop().height())


class Tab_bank_statement(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.window_dashboard_bank_statement()
        
    def window_dashboard_bank_statement(self):
        df = pd.read_feather('bank_statement.feather')
        df_pivot = df.groupby(
            pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'),
            group_keys=False).agg({'Inflow': 'sum','Outflow': 'sum'}).reset_index()

        fig = go.Figure()
        fig._config = {'displayModeBar': False}
        fig = px.bar(pd.DataFrame(df_pivot), x = 'Date', y = ['Inflow', 'Outflow'], barmode='group')

        def click_event(ace, points, state):
            print(ace, points, state)

        fig.data[0].on_click(
            lambda ace, points, state:
                click_event(ace=ace, points=points,state=state))

        browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))

        self.grid.addWidget(browser, 0, 2)


tab.addTab(Tab_bank_statement(), "Bank_statement")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tab.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to return the column name by coordinates on the plane using the plotly `on_click` method

[image]

Comment: Please ensure that the code you're providing exactly corresponds to the one you're using, as I can spot some important issues probably related to indentation. Also, avoid creating nested classes (especially if created within functions) unless you **really** know what you're doing and **why**. 99% of the times, it's not just useless, it's plainly *wrong*.

Comment: Comments taken into account